# LDAPS: openldap bind successful even after deleting CA certificate from root directory

Tags: openssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, openldap, client-certificates

In my code I am using openldap library to start tls to a ldap server.
Using global LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR option to set ca certificate directory.
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR,"");

Now,
STEP 1 : Correct certificate is in place and ldap_sasl_bind_sto ldap server is successful (as expected).

STEP 2 : I am deleting the certificate from the directory as I don't want openldap to use the older certificate, but even after this the bind is getting successful.

If the certificate is loaded in openldap's cache, I am not able to find any way to reset it.

My problem is exactly same as : [starttls successful even after deleting CA from the ca dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457034/starttls-successful-even-after-deleting-ca-from-the-ca-dir)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by reinitializing the TLS Context.

int is_server = 0;
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX, &is_server);